# Is EJB MDB is JMS Push model or Pull model?

Tags: jms

We all know using EJB MDB we can consume the messages through Pub/Sub or with P2P. When i saw the comparision usually according to JMS specification, Pub/Sub is using push model and P2P is using Pull model.

Is it true, can't i consume the P2P messages in MDB using push model?

Should we do any configuration changes or it is purely an server providers implementation or both.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are speaking about difference between Topic and QUeue. So, Pub/Sub it is Topic and P2P it is Queue. Implementing push or pull model depends of server and you cannot change that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Pub/Sub and P2P is how the messages are distributed. A message sent to a topic (via Pub/Sub) is distributed to every consumer. A message sent via P2P is sent to one consumer.

The MDB programming model is a push one. Whether this is implemented as push vs pull is down to how the Resource Adapter and messaging system is implemented. WebSphere MQ and the WebSphere Application Server default messaging provider are both able to push messages to the application server for both Pub/Sub and P2P.